# Android drawable resources getting created in a debug folder?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I'm building an Android app using Android Studio & Kotlin. Historically, when I've added new image drawbles:

[image]

they were saved to the following folder: `\app\src\main\res`

However, recently (potentially after an Android Studio update?) new image drawables now wind up here: `\app\src\debug\res`. I haven't intentionally meant for that to happen. Now my drawables are split between the two locations. What caused this change? How do I switch it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the right "Res Directory", "main" when adding the drawable:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to set 'main' as the default one ? . If I start import from Resource manager, I am able to get 'main' as default. But if I right click on the drawable folder and import, by default it shows debug mode.

Comment: I believe it picks the last used one. Or at least for that project.